# Error observed during SVN Dump of Repository (Visual SVN)

Tags: svn, visualsvn-server

I am moving repositories from one server to another as we are migrating data centres. And, while performing an SVN dump, I am encountering the following error:

```
* Dumped revision 547.
svnadmin: E185003: Invalid diff stream: [tgt] insn 0 starts beyond the target view position
```

Why would I get such an error on a dump and how do I resolve this? We have close to 11,000 revisions in the one repo, so hoping there is an easy solution to work around this issue.

All my online searches are connected to other SVN functions and nothing specific to svnadmin dump command getting such an error.

Thanks in advance.
Paul

Answer (score 0):

When you move VisualSVN Server from one server computer to another, please, read and follow instructions from the article [KB166: Migrating VisualSVN Server to another computer](https://www.visualsvn.com/support/topic/00166/). You do not need to use `svnadmin dump` and `svnadmin load` in most cases when you migrate the server to another machine.

> We have close to 11,000 revisions in the one repo, so hoping there is an easy solution to work around this issue.

The easy solution is **not** to use `svnadmin dump` and `svnadmin load` during this migration and simply copy your repositories per **Step 2. Migrate repositories** from the article [KB166](https://www.visualsvn.com/support/topic/00166/). However, it is still recommended to solve the problem after you migrate the server and the repos.

> Why would I get such an error on a dump and how do I resolve this?

Revision 548 is corrupted in this repository or you have encountered some bug. First, I'd recommend that you double-check that you use up to date Subversion command line tools. If you get the same errors with up to date tools, I think that you could contact support@visualsvn.com and we will help you fix this corruption.

In order to prevent such problems in future, please, make sure that

- use up to date Subversion server version,
- your storage is healthy,
- you regularly [verify](https://www.visualsvn.com/support/topic/00115/) your repositories
- you [backup](https://www.visualsvn.com/server/features/backup/) them on regular basis.

Comment: We are moving from Visual SVN to Collab SVN

Comment: In my scenario, we are moving from Visual SVN to CollabNET SVN. I have tried to do an incremental build and exclude Rev 547, but when I run the import on the dump, I get a checksum mismatch. However, come to think of it, I am not sure if I specifically excluded the corrupt revision, so trying again.